# RMarkdown ioslides presentation in HD

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

Is there a simple way to configure ioslides presentations for higher resolutions?
I know of the widescreen option:

```
---
output:
ioslides_presentation:
widescreen: true
---
```

which increases width a little bit, but I wonder if there's a parameter or simple CSS change which allows for higher resolutions...

Comment: You probably mean "zooming". Normally I use Google Chrome, and I press `F` (fullscreen), then `Ctrl + Plus` a few times to zoom into the page a little bit.

Comment: thanks @Yihui i'll check whether that works for me on a couple of high-res big screens.

Comment: Can't accept comments, but this works well. In general I would choose ioslides over .Rpres in the meantime.

Comment: Copied and pasted as an "answer" :)

Comment: this is a bit late, but your edit looks inappropriate to me -- (1) it asks a second questions (SO posts should contain a single question) and (2) it's not really a programming question, but a tool/framework question ...

Comment: @Ben Bolker I agree it might not be my best question w.r.t. SO etiquette. I am willing to improve and would also consider deleting it if that's what you want. ad framework vs programming: SO is where the R guys are at - I guess it's hard to find a better person to answer my specific question than Yihui. It's not like you can go to tons of place and get the same quality of R answers. Anyway, what do you want me to do?

Comment: I would recommend deleting it (not the whole question - just your EDIT: section).  It is a good question, but this just isn't the right place for it (if you posted it as a separate question on SO it would probably get closed).  [This discussion on Github](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/507) suggests that you're right, and that slidify and ioslides are better than Rpres for general-purpose presentation formats ...

Comment: You mean the edit or the entire question ? Guess that would be a little too much since some people found it helpful. 7-8 upvotes are decent for R I guess. I am on the phone and edit / delete tomorrow.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You probably mean "zooming". Normally I use Google Chrome, and I press `F` (fullscreen), then `Ctrl + Plus` a few times to zoom into the page a little bit.