# RMarkdown presentation in higher resolution

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Is there any way to change RMarkdown slides to higher resolution? The previous question ([RMarkdown ioslides presentation in HD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782595/rmarkdown-ioslides-presentation-in-hd)) was about "zooming" the slides.

I'm more concerned about the size of images in the presentation. In default, it's possible to use image with height up to about 600px.

How change the default resolution of Markdown slides and therefore use images in a higher resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using custom CSS.

First, create a CSS file in the same directory as your presentation, say "bigslides.css", with this content (adjust slide size to taste):

```
body slides > slide
{
  height: 900px;
  width: 900px;
  margin-top: -450px;    /* half of height */
}
```

Then, in your document's YAML header, add the CSS file:

```
---
...
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: bigslides.css
---
```

You may have to adjust a few other CSS classes as well to get the effect you're after, but once you've got the above set up it should be as simple as adding rules to your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks, It's almost working - there is only one problem. Slides are placed in slightly lower part of the screen, and as a result  the bottom of the slide is invisible. The example is in my edited question.

Comment: Adjust the top margin of the slide to accommodate the additional height (see edited answer). Note that at 900px the slide may overfill the viewer window so you may need to adjust its size too, depending on the resolution of your display.

Comment: Yes, of course - use of big slides is proper only in case of using screens in higher resolution. Thanks a lot!