# How to make rmarkdown ioslides widescreen

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, knitr, ioslides

How can I make the ioslides html presentation (that comes from rendering an rmarkdown document with `output: ioslides_presentation` in the YAML header) widescreen?

I have learned that [the output size is fixed at 1024x768 pixels](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/185#issuecomment-486811422), but I assume there *is* some way to change that. In a CSS file? An HTML template? Rmarkdown? Knitr? Pandoc?

[This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782595/rmarkdown-ioslides-presentation-in-hd) asks basically the same question, but the accepted answer does not actually give a method to change the presentation dimensions.

I would like the output to be 1920x1080 pixels, or 1366x768 pixels - if that makes it easier. I'm looking for a 16:9 aspect ratio instead of the default 4:3 ratio. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Pressing `w` should work?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer is there any way to make that the default?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58513400/1777111

Answer (score 0):

In the YAML header you can add this to make it 16:9 by default:

```
---
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    widescreen: true
---
```