# Make ioslides default to widescreen

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

In ioslides you can make the slide widescreen by pressing 'w'.  Is there any setting in the css or yaml header to make widescreen the default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/ioslides-presentation.html#visual-appearance).

```
---
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    widescreen: true
---
```

Comment: thanks.  For some reason that didn't come up no matter how many ways i googled it.